# python. how to export to csv file after gather data on web

Tags: python, csv

I did some web scraping with selenium and was able to generate to print a table with the data I need to export (see image below). How can now export it to csv (place a .csv in a specific folder with todays date).
Thanks a lot for your inputs.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select



path_to_chromedriver = 'C:\python34\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe' # change path as needed
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)
url = 'http://test.com'
browser.get(url)

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='query_choice']/option[text()='60 days']").click() # working to select DLP

browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type=\"submit\"]').click() # working to press submit

for tag in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="page1"]/table'):
    print (tag.text)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your table is a list

```
with open('saveTo\Directory\file.csv','w') as f:
    f.write(','.join(tableData))
```

Where you can technically, call the f.write method on each line of the table as soon as you have it, but change the 'w' parameter to 'a' to append to the file

Comment: I placed that code on my program, and gave me an error of path. How should the saveTo\Directory\file.csv be wriiten? Can by like C:\test\test\file.csv right? The file csv itself needs to exist prior to run the program? Thanks a lot.

Comment: tableData is what in this case? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, change saveTo .. to the place where you want it saved. If you just specify file.csv then it will be written in the same ditectory as where the script was executed from.

tableData is a list of a single row such as:
[column1Item, column2Item, ....]

Comment: could be  f.write(','.join(tag.text.split()))